# JavaFX unmanaged like context menu

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a SearchTextField that allows me to Type into a TextField, then a ListView narrows the selection on what is typed.

The ListView is not visible until you enter the TextField and is unmanaged.
The only problem I have is that any items below the TextField overlap the ListView.

Is there any way to make the ListView appear on top of anything below the TextField (Like a context menu does)?

Comment: ControlsFX has a similar feature called as [AutoComplete TextFields](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#textfields) and they use a [PopupControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html) for the same.

Comment: This looks awesome, but looks like the lowest version is for 8u20, so I'll have to make  something for 7.0_79. PopupControl does look like a good idea.